# FileNotFoundError Using listdir in python

Tags: python, directory, listdir

so I have a directory with a few subdirectories in it and I am trying to iterate through all the subdirectories I have (each subdirectory has a bunch of files in it that I'm splitting up into smaller files). i've been trying to use `os.listdir` but I keep getting this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mFAPA'

This subdirectory definitely exists, so I'm not sure why this keeps happening

```
for dir in os.listdir('../conv_files'):
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
```

I was trying to use the for loops to go through each directory and then in each directory go through each file. The error is on the second line of code, once it's in the parent directory it for some reason can't do the `for filename in os.listdir(dir)` part. Any suggestions?

Comment: your error might be occurring in the second loop maybe? Can you post the directory structure as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use os.walk() which traverses into each subdirectory and files inside a given directory. Refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/os-walk-python/ for more details

```
for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk('../conv_files'):
   #add your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

**syntax**: os.listdir(path)

**Parameters**:
path (optional) : path of the directory

**Return Type**: This method returns the list of all files and directories in the specified path. The return type of this method is list.

in your first nested loop, it consists of the file names but os.listdir(path) requires path in it.