# How can I create a linked list that stores each folder of the current path as a Node and each file of those folders as an item on Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

Let's say that I have the following folders in a path called `C:\Users\Test`:

[image: Current Folders]

Every single one of them contains only images (In PNG format) with a different name (also none of them contains subfolders).

How could build a Python program that creates a data structure for the folders above in `C:\Users\Test` that looks like the one below after double clicking it?

```
struct the_linked_list{

Color = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']
Cuerpo = ['Body.png']
Fondo = ['Background.png']
Ojos = ['eyes1.png', 'eyes2.png', 'eyes3.png']
Pinzas = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png']
Puas = ['x.png', 'y.png'. 'z.png']
}
```

-Assume that the names of the filenames within those folders are those provided in the example above, respectively.

-The created data structure must have set the names of its nodes as the names of the folders, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the `os.listdir()` function which returns a list of the files in a specified directory. Then you could use this a few times to get a list of the directories you wanted in the linked list. Then, iterate through this list, creating a new object for each iteration, and calling `os.listdir` on this directory to get a list of the files.

Here's an implementation of what I did:

```
import os

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, files):
        self.dir_name = name
        self.files = files
        self.next = None
    
def add(head, new_node):
    '''Adds new node to end of linked list'''
    curr_node = head
    while (curr_node.next != None):
        curr_node = curr_node.next
    
    curr_node.next = new_node
    
# Main method

path = input()
list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
head = None

# Get files and add directory to LL
for dir in list_of_file_contents:
    path_to_dir = f"{path}\{dir}"

    if (os.path.isdir(path_to_dir)):
        file_list = os.listdir(path_to_dir)

        if (head == None):
            head = Node(dir, file_list)
        else:
            add(head, Node(dir, file_list))
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error that says ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system can't find the specified path``` after I typed ```C:\Users\Test``` as input, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it seems that if ```C:\Users\Test``` happens to have some files that have a ```.psd``` extension, they make your program go wrong

Comment: Ok I think an error could occur if you have files as well as directories in the `C:\Users\Test`. But I'm not sure about I updated my solution.

Comment: Also, `os.walk` might be of use. Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659715/filenotfounderror-using-listdir-in-python). I'm not sure about the `.psd` extensions. I believe they should print as regular `.png` files print anyways. But I'm not sure about that one.